Insert an entity into existing list using a positional predicate, using Specter
Using Specter and given this xs:

[{:identifier "Green", :idx 2} {:identifier "Indigo", :idx 4} {:identifier "Violet", :idx 5}]

I want to insert this entity:

{:identifier "Blue", :idx 3}

So the result becomes:

[{:identifier "Green", :idx 2} {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3} {:identifier "Indigo", :idx 4} {:identifier "Violet", :idx 5}]

The :idx values in xs are guaranteed to be in order. So I tried this in Specter, and got into all sorts of trouble:
(s/setval [s/ALL (s/pred #(> (:idx %) idx)) s/FIRST s/BEFORE-ELEM] {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3} xs)

What I want to achieve in English:

Navigate to first entity where value of :idx in an entity contained in xs is greater than the idx function argument.
Insert new entity before the :idx entity found at step 1.

Here's what I need to do written in Clojure:
(defn insert-inbetween-by-idx [xs identifier idx]
  (let [insert {:identifier identifier :idx idx}
        b4-idx (filterv (comp (partial > idx) :idx) xs)
        after-idx (filter (comp (partial < idx) :idx) xs)]
    (reduce into [b4-idx [insert] after-idx])))

Can someone help me by writing this function in Specter?

You don't need specter for that.
(let [data      [{:identifier "Green", :idx 2} {:identifier "Indigo", :idx 4} {:identifier "Violet", :idx 5}]
      new-entry {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3}]
  (into [] cat (-> (split-with #(-> % :idx (< (:idx new-entry))) data)
                 (interleave-all [[new-entry]]))))
=>
[{:identifier "Green", :idx 2}
 {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3}
 {:identifier "Indigo", :idx 4}
 {:identifier "Violet", :idx 5}]

If you must use specter, then you could do:
(let [data      [{:identifier "Green", :idx 2} {:identifier "Indigo", :idx 4} {:identifier "Violet", :idx 5}]
        new-entry {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3}
        location  (some-fn (fn [a]
                             (->> a
                               (keep-indexed (fn [index value]
                                               (when (< (:idx new-entry) (:idx value))
                                                 index)))
                               (first)))
                    count)]
    (->> data
      (r/setval [(r/srange-dynamic location location)] [new-entry])))


As above, not an answer about specter, but in case your data items have unique :idx values, you could probably chose to change the collection data type to a sorted set. In this case inserting the value into the right place is as trivial as calling conj:
(defn compare-by [f] (fn [a b] (compare (f a) (f b))))

(def data-sorted (apply sorted-set-by (compare-by :idx) data))

user> (conj data-sorted {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3})

#{{:identifier "Green", :idx 2}
  {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3}
  {:identifier "Indigo", :idx 4}
  {:identifier "Violet", :idx 5}}

user> (conj data-sorted
            {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3}
            {:identifier "Blue", :idx 1}
            {:identifier "Blue", :idx 7})

#{{:identifier "Blue", :idx 1}
  {:identifier "Green", :idx 2}
  {:identifier "Blue", :idx 3}
  {:identifier "Indigo", :idx 4}
  {:identifier "Violet", :idx 5}
  {:identifier "Blue", :idx 7}}


